# Return all values not within a radius

Tags: postgis, sql

I am a new postgis user and I have a simple question.
My intention is to know all point values that not have a line feature near (10 meters of tolerance) How can I do this?

I've tried to find by ST_Dwithin operator, but I need the opposite result. All line features are not within the point radius. Something similar to "not covered by..."

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. SQL questions here are expected to contain SQL code (at a minimum, including the table names and geometry column name(s)).  We'll also need you to [Edit] the question to provide more information about the total number of features, and the number of expected features in your result set (this can impact which of the two principal approaches to take).

Comment: related but ST_Intersects with LEFT Join https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/postgis-select-features-that-do-not-intersect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM WHERE ST_DWithin() )`

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM t2
  WHERE ST_DWithin( t1, t2, m )
);
```

This will return all `t1` not within `m` of `t2`

Comment: Exactly what I looking for.
Work correctly
Thank you so much.
Regards!