# PostGIS: Using nearest (<->), and ST_ClosestPoint in a create table

Tags: postgis, sql

I have the following datasets stored in PostGIS 9.5 with all the relevent indexes built.

1. Collected Points - over 4 million points
2. Polygons - almost 5000 multi polygons (and they are multi polygons)
3. Road Lines - over 5 millions linestrings
4. Access Points - 68k point features

For each Collected Point I need to test whether it is in a Polygon, if it is then select the nearest Access Point, if it is not in the Polygon, then select the closest point from the lines.

I have tried a number of methods and the closest I can get to the right SQL was this:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS 
WITH polygon AS (
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) as geom FROM polygons
)

SELECT
cp.*,
CASE
    WHEN ST_Intersects(cp.geom, polygon.geom) THEN (Select ap.geom FROM access_points ap ORDER BY ap.geom <-> cp.geom LIMIT 1) 
    ELSE ST_CLosestPoint(l.geom, cp.geom)
END AS closest_geom
FROM
polygon,
collected_points cp,
lines l
```

this code is running but even on a sample of 150 Collected Points the query has been running for a long time.

Maybe I am trying to do too much in a query or need to use more subqueries or CTS statements.

Can someone please suggest a better solution

Comment: this is going to likely be real slow as bounding box on a linestring may not be useful for closest point type ops and that function won't do any good.

Comment: For instance if `[-100,+100]` is the same `<->` to `0,0` as `-1,+1` despite both of the points in  `[-100,+100]` being massively further away.

Comment: By unioning all polygons you will get no help from the index. Take a look at this answer for a better approach to find non intersecting https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/select-features-that-do-not-intersect-in-postgis/4508#4508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get decent performance, decompose your linestring to points.

```
CREATE TABLE pts AS
  SELECT (dp).geom AS lnpt, l.geom
  FROM lines AS l
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS dp;

CREATE INDEX ON pts USING gist (lnpt);
```

Then run something like this,

```
SELECT cp.geom, COALESCE(ap.geom, l.geom) AS wanted
FROM collected_points AS cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ap.geom
  FROM access_points
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM polygon AS p
    WHERE ST_Intersects( cp.geom, p.geom )
  )
  ORDER BY ap.geom <=> cp.geom
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) AS ap
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT l.geom
  FROM pts
  ORDER BY ap.geom <=> pts.lnpt
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) AS l
  ON ap IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Just trying it out but getting a syntax error ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 14: ) AS ap, have tried editing but unsure what is causing it

Comment: @tjmgis fixed now

Comment: Be aware that you will get a different answer if you decompose the points. Tehe closest point on the line might be between the vertex points.

Comment: If that's what your looking for you're going to have to calculate the closest point on *every* line and see which one is closer for every point in the result set. That is to say, it's simply going to be slow (afaik)

Comment: @EvanCarroll thank you for you help. Never used a JOIN LATERAL and it is fantastic.

Comment: @NicklasAvén luckily my line work had plenty of vertices so this worked but you are right the alternative having tested is to use a second JOIN LATERAL similar to the first and then use ST_ClosestPoint and the closest line found using <->

Comment: @EvanCarroll If he has PostGIS 2.2 with PG 9.5+ he can order by distance also against lines with proper recheck after index-scan. From that he can use st_closestpoint. But the recheck will make it slower than only points of course.