# Finding points where another point layer does NOT intersect a polygon layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I am using PostGreSQL to deal with 3 layers. I have two point layers(points A and points B) and a polygon layer. Some of the points in both A & B fall within the same polygon. I want to find all of the points in points A where points B do not intersect with the polygon layer. How can I intersect B and the polygons while only needing the points from point layer A?

Comment: so is this a multipolygon?

Comment: yes it is. Im working with a parcel polygons.

Comment: post the SQL you have tried already Kray Dizzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has always been a little tricky; simply joining two tables by *non-intersection* results in their conditioned cartesian product.
The key here is to sieve the polygons by exclusion first and then join the third table by intersection. I'll use a `NOT EXISTS` construct to get only those polygons that do not intersect with `point_b`s points, and join that result set with `point_a`:

```
SELECT a.<id>,
       a.<geom>
FROM point_a AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT p.<geom>
  FROM polygon AS p
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM point_b AS b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(b.<geom>, p.<geom>)
  )
) AS excl
ON ST_Intersects(a.<geom>, excl.<geom>);
```

I found this to be most efficient in terms of speed. There are other ways, e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/select-features-that-do-not-intersect-in-postgis/136177) (old) post has some more, including the above and one doing it nicely wrong.

Note: For larger tables you might want to `ST_Dump` your *MultiPolygon*s into a new (indexed) table. In general, *Multi*Geometries are not best suited for spatial relation analysis.