# PostgreSQL: Copy the line segment together in another table without copying the intersection with another line segment

Tags: postgresql, linestring

Presently these linesegments are in different rows but in the same table and numbers shown in the image are the ids of respective linestrings. I want to copy linesegment 350, 333, 352,4,.. in one table while 1601, 1602,356, 576,580,344,.. in another table. In terms of algebra set A members in one table and set B in another though there is intersection seen visually. This is a representative sample and these sets have more ids than mentioned here and have more sets than two A and B. Can we do using queries in postgis or using python script

[image: Postgres table shown in QGIS for linestring]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand translat your question correctly, I would go in this direction:

1) collect all the lines, for example by street name or by condition if they (segments) touch each other;

2) create two copies of them:

`SELECT * INTO roads_1 FROM source_table;
SELECT * INTO roads_2 FROM source_table;`

3) remove intersecting streets:

`DELETE FROM roads_1 as t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM roads_1 as t2 
WHERE t2.id<t1.id AND ST_Intersects(t2.geom, t1.geom));`

and

`DELETE FROM roads_2 as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM roads_2 as t2 
WHERE t2.id<t1.id AND ST_Intersects(t2.geom, t1.geom));`

edit - addition:

variant 1 -

`1.1) create table table_a as
SELECT a.id, a.geom as geom FROM source_table a JOIN
source_table b ON ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom)
WHERE a.id=350 or a.id=333 or a.id=352 or a.id=4
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom;`

`1.2) create table table_b as
SELECT a.id, a.geom as geom FROM source_table a JOIN
source_table b ON ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom) WHERE a.id=1601 or a.id=1602 or a.id=356 or a.id=576 or a.id=580 or a.id=344
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom;`

variant 2 -

`2.1) create table table_a as
SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) as geom FROM source_table a JOIN
source_table b ON ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom)
WHERE a.id=350 or a.id=333 or a.id=352 or a.id=4;`

`2.2) create table table_b as
SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) as geom FROM source_table a JOIN
source_table b ON ST_Intersects (a.geom,b.geom) WHERE a.id=1601 or a.id=1602 or a.id=356 or a.id=576 or a.id=580 or a.id=344;`

Comment: What if we have more linestrings, I anticipate that we can use union and intersection or something from available functions in Postgres that can take care of line segments connected to form single multilinestring. Take a scenario of Road networks having square and is main long road passing through big city e.g. Oxford street of london which has several line segments.

Comment: In that case, merging is not the goal but want to remove the unnecessary nodes. while I just want to merge and address the continuous (visually at the moment) line segments probably using any existing available functions

Comment: Now it's clear to me that you want to divide the GEODATA into two tables, with the condition that there are no intersections between them...

Comment: Yes, you got that. Let me try your hints to see what happens there. Just one issue that I sense is, the linesegments have visual similarity at this moment for example from fig., id 580 and 344 cannot be put into one table using any column name (street name or other_tags ).Thank you.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/select-features-that-do-not-intersect-in-postgis/4508#4508

Comment: Thanks Cyril, I anticipated that there might be some geometry thing that can be implemented to find if two lines are having 180 degrees (straight line) or less than 100-degree angle(crossing point at the end of lines) so that we can use the loop to check the lines but once I get used to these I might love to do these using python in QGIS. However, for now, I manually deleted unwanted lines in QGIS and put the same name using a query in Postgis in a table.

Comment: Not for that, as I understood the translation of your question, so I offered various solutions, but as I understand it, it's still not the solutions that you were looking for :-)...

Comment: Cyril, I used your queries during the process and your previous queries were also useful but unfortunately, I did not copy, Do you mind adding those that were using if id equals. Time and efforts are appreciated.

Comment: @Aaron, I added codes, I hope this is what you are asking ...